# Как прокрутить блок при прокрутке второго блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно осуществить такое?

У второго блока подключен jScrollPane, у него есть вертикальная и горизонтальная прокрутка.

Когда прокручиваю этот блок по горизонтали, нужно что бы первый блок тоже прокручивался вслед за ним. Каким образом это сделать можно?

Скрипт jScrollPane к первому блоку не вариант, т.к. по горизонтали он статичен.

```js
$(function() {
  var block1 = $('.jspPane');
  console.log(block1);
  var block2 = $('.event-time__time');
  console.log(block2);
  block1.onscroll = function() {
    block2.scrollTop = block1.scrollTop;
    block2.scrollLeft = block1.scrollLeft;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можете отслеживать скролл с помощью события `onScroll`, а после значения скролла присваивать другому блоку:

```
block1.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  block2.scrollTop = block1.scrollTop;
  block2.scrollLeft = block1.scrollLeft;
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var block1 = $('.jspPane');
  console.log(block1);
  var block2 = $('.event-time__time');
  console.log(block2);
  block1.onscroll = function() {
    block2.scrollTop = block1.scrollTop;
    block2.scrollLeft = block1.scrollLeft;
  };
});
```

Comment: будет ли такая прокрутка одновременной со вторым блоком? или же перемещение будет после?

Comment: Перемещение будет после, но задержка настолько минимальная, что можно сказать, что они одновременно будут перемещаться.

Comment: как я понимаю отслеживание делается так:                               block1.onscroll = function() {
      var scrolled = block1.pageXOffset;
      block1.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        block2.scrollTop = block1.scrollTop;
        block2.scrollLeft = block1.scrollLeft;
      });
    }

Comment: Не верно, во первых значение `pageXOffset` относится к самой странице, и существует только в объекте `window`, во вторых событие  `block1.onscroll` и `block1.addEventListener("scroll", ... )` полностью одинаковы, и получается что при скролле, добавляться еще одно событие. Код который я написал, уже включает в себе обработчик и присваивание скролла, либо можете заменить строку `block1.addEventListener("scroll", ... )` на `block1.onscroll`, как Вам будет удобно.

Comment: ругается Uncaught TypeError: block1.onscroll is not a function, я так понимаю что onscroll не успевает определить переменную  $(function() {
    var block1 = $('.jspPane');
    console.log(block1);
    var block2 = $('.event-time__time');
    console.log(block2);
    block1.onscroll(function() {
      block2.scrollTop = block1.scrollTop;
      block2.scrollLeft = block1.scrollLeft;
    });
});

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию `block1.onscroll`, в то время когда нужно ей присвоить функцию, вот так будет правильнее: `$(function() {
 var block1 = $('.jspPane');
 console.log(block1);
 var block2 = $('.event-time__time');
 console.log(block2);
 block1.onscroll = function() { block2.scrollTop = block1.scrollTop; block2.scrollLeft = block1.scrollLeft; };
});`